# Equality case in elementary form of Holder's Inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

A well known elementary formulation of Holder's Inequality can be stated as follows:

Let $a_{ij}$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, k; j = 1, 2, \dots, n$ be positive real numbers, and let $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_k$ be positive real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p_i} = 1$.  Then we have

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n} \prod_{i = 1}^{k} a_{ij} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{k} \left ( \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{ij}^{p_i} \right )^{\frac{1}{p_i}}.$$

Does anyone know when equality occurs in this inequality?  Any insights on the equality case and/or a proof would be appreciated.

---

I have seen several proofs of the two sequence case.  Here is one, from Cvetkovski's *Inequalities*:
[image]

Perhaps this argument can be generalized to prove the above result.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the usual proof of generalized Holder's proceeds by induction from the usual Holder's inequality, the equality case is precisely the same. In other words, if $v_j$ denotes the vector with components $a_{ij}^p$, then equality occurs iff all the vectors $v_j$ are parallel.

Comment: Thank you -- could you direct me to a source where I can see the details of the proof?

Comment: I think most first-year real analysis courses cover a proof of the generalized integral version. It was an exercise in our book (Folland's Real Analysis). Someone wrote up a solution to that exercise here: http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/grads/clungstr/real_analysis/hwset10.pdf